# Transferring water from one sump to another

Tags: sump-pump

My house has two underground sumps that store water. I was wondering if there was an easy way to transfer water from one of the sumps to the other. Would a small manual suction pipe (like the ones used for draining out an aquarium) work?

---

p.s.:
The context is this -- It's raining now (after a long time), and only one of the sumps is connected to the pipe that collects the rain water. The other sump is what's connected to the tank that feeds the solar water heater, and it's almost empty now. If I can fill the rain water into the other sump, I can use it for the hot water.

Comment: "Manual suction pipe"? Do you mean a siphon? Why wouldn't a standard sump pump work?

Comment: @isherwood Yes, I meant a siphon. Sump pump will work.. but I was wondering something diy-easy and quick that I could set up in an hour or two..

Comment: What's the goal here? When you say "store water", do you mean for later use, and if so for what?

Comment: Siphons only work if you have a height differential. I doubt you do in this case.

Comment: @DanielGriscom The context is this -- It's raining now (after a long time), and only one of the sumps is connected to the pipe that collects the rain water.  The other sump is what's connected to the tank that feeds the solar water heater, and it's almost empty now. If I can fill the rain water into the other sump, I can use it for the hot water.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks.. Yes, there isn't a height differential, but they are right next to each other..  I'll probably just get a regular pump.

Comment: Could you tap into the bottom of each tank and run a pipe with a valve in the center. it would only drain down until each tank had the same level but very cheap.

Comment: Thans for the additional detail: you should edit this into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A manual suction pipe (or perhaps a commerial siphon?) will transfer fluid until the fluid level is equivalent (or level). A commercial siphon will operate for a perhaps a couple of hours; a simple pipe or a hose will operate for a 20 or 30 minutes perhaps. But siphons will eventually fail as fluid evaporates and bubbles eventually fill in the siphon's reservoir.

How long the siphon will continue to operate depends on the rate of bubble formation, which depends mostly on the height of the hose (gravity will cause a vacuum at the top) and temperature (cold water will allow a siphon to operate longer than steaming hot water).

[image]